# Keep new window settings after using MoveWindow

Tags: c#

After a long time searching and trying I finally succeeded to move all the screens from the second screen to the primary screen.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rectangle rectangle);

private void putAllWindowsOnPrimairyScreen(){

int procesWidth, procesHeight;

    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
       IntPtr id = p.MainWindowHandle;
       Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
       GetWindowRect(id, ref rect);
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
       {
          if (rect.Height > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) procesHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
          else procesHeight = rect.Height;
          if (rect.Width > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) procesWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
          else procesWidth = rect.Width;
          System.Console.WriteLine(p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductName);
          MoveWindow(id, 0, 0, procesWidth, procesHeight, true);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the screen, in my case Firefox, won't stay at the primairy screen... I can open it once and the second time I try, it restored to the second screen.

How can I make it stay on the primairy screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't, in general, force other programs to do your bidding - unless those other programs are also written by you and/or there's some defined protocol for you to instruct it to do things.

Comment: That's a shame... Is there no other way to fix this? I found [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is there any posibility to edit these options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, trail and error I fixed this problem by editing the code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rectangle rectangle);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
    public const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
    public const int SC_NEXTWINDOW = 0xF040;
    public const int SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11;
    public const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    public const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
    public const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
    public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
    public const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    public const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;
    public const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
    public const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
    public const int SW_SHOWMINNOCATIVE = 7;
    public const int SW_SHOWNA = 8;
    public const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
    public const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WINDOWRECTANGLE
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Puts all the active screens on the primairy screen.
    /// </summary>
    public static void putAllWindowsOnPrimairyScreen()
    {
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            int procesWidth, procesHeigth, defaultProcesWidth, defaultProcesHeigth;
            IntPtr id = p.MainWindowHandle;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                WINDOWRECTANGLE rect = new WINDOWRECTANGLE();
                WINDOWRECTANGLE defaultrect = new WINDOWRECTANGLE();
                GetWindowRect(id, ref rect);
                ShowWindow(id, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
                GetWindowRect(id, ref defaultrect);
                if (rect.Left > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width || rect.Left < 0 || rect.Right > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width || rect.Right < 0 || rect.Top > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height || rect.Top < 0 || rect.Bottom > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height || rect.Bottom < 0)
                {
                    procesWidth = rect.Right - rect.Left;
                    procesHeigth = rect.Bottom - rect.Top;
                    defaultProcesWidth = defaultrect.Right - defaultrect.Left;
                    defaultProcesHeigth = defaultrect.Bottom - defaultrect.Top;
                    PostMessage(p.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_NEXTWINDOW, 0);
                    MoveWindow(id, 0, 0, defaultProcesWidth, defaultProcesHeigth, true);
                    p.Refresh();
                    if (procesHeigth >= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height || procesWidth >= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) ShowWindow(id, SW_MAXIMIZE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So it is posible to force a external window to an other screen and let it stay there. After copy and pasting this code compleet, just activate the method `putAllWindowsOnPrimairyScreen()`